# c# generic object[] adding another element

Tags: c#, .net, object

I have

```
Object[] a = {"steve","jill"};
```

How do I add another element?

```
a[2]="new york"; //doesn't work of course
```

there isn't a `a.Add("new york");` or `a.Push("new york");`

Comment: You can't alter the size of an array after it is created. If you need dynamic size, use a List<object> instead.

Comment: Read this with cool examples - https://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using *array* as the collection, you have to `Resize`:

```
  Array.Resize(ref a, a.Length + 1);

  a[a.Length - 1] = "new york";
```

However, a much better approach is to use `List<T>` which is specially designed for this purpose:

```
  List<object> a = new List<object>()
    { "steve", "jill" };

  a.Add("new york");
```

Comment: NOTE: Internally `List<T>` is an array which is dynamically resized when needed. Question is, should the _op_ use `List<object>` or `ArrayList`

Comment: @ja72: `ArrayList` is a *deprecated*, that's why `List<Object>` is preferable

Answer (score 0):

```
Object[] a = { "steve", "jill" };
Object[] b = new Object[3];
a.CopyTo(b, 0);
a= b;
a[2] = "new york";
```

Comment: I agree about using a list but this is some 10 year old code.  And Intellisence doesn't show me that I have a resize.

Comment: user5903880 this is actually the best (most efficient) answer, because `Array.Resize` does something like this but with more overhead https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,71074deaf111c4e3

Comment: So long since I had to do anything like this it was difficult to remember what I really needed to do is resize the array.

Answer (score 0):

The lazy inefficient version:

```
Object[] a = {"steve","jill"};

a = a.Concat(new Object[]{"new york"}).ToArray(); // add

a = new Object[]{"new york"}.Concat(a).ToArray(); // insert
```